# Micronaut application server start up errors

Tags: netty, micronaut

I'm setting up the micronaut application, but deployment getting failed with following exceptions:

```
23:47:03.769 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter]
Message: Illegal field modifiers in class io/micronaut/web/router/RouteMatch: 0x82
Path Taken: new NettyHttpServer(NettyHttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration,ApplicationContext applicationContext,[Router router],RequestArgumentSatisfier requestArgumentSatisfier,MediaTypeCodecRegistry mediaTypeCodecRegistry,NettyCustomizableResponseTypeHandlerRegistry customizableResponseTypeHandlerRegistry,StaticResourceResolver resourceResolver,ExecutorService ioExecutor,ThreadFactory threadFactory,ExecutorSelector executorSelector,Optional serverSslBuilder,List outboundHandlers,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory) --> new DefaultRouter([Collection builders])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter]
Message: Illegal field modifiers in class io/micronaut/web/router/RouteMatch: 0x82
Path Taken: new NettyHttpServer(NettyHttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration,ApplicationContext applicationContext,[Router router],RequestArgumentSatisfier requestArgumentSatisfier,MediaTypeCodecRegistry mediaTypeCodecRegistry,NettyCustomizableResponseTypeHandlerRegistry customizableResponseTypeHandlerRegistry,StaticResourceResolver resourceResolver,ExecutorService ioExecutor,ThreadFactory threadFactory,ExecutorSelector executorSelector,Optional serverSslBuilder,List outboundHandlers,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory) --> new DefaultRouter([Collection builders])
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1492)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2143)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1829)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1809)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:987)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:981)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$NettyHttpServerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1474)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2143)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1829)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1809)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1006)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:577)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:135)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:288)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:274)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field modifiers in class io/micronaut/web/router/RouteMatch: 0x82
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouteBuilder.buildRoute(DefaultRouteBuilder.java:392)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouteBuilder.buildRoute(DefaultRouteBuilder.java:383)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouteBuilder.GET(DefaultRouteBuilder.java:252)
    at io.micronaut.management.endpoint.processors.ReadEndpointRouteBuilder.registerRoute(ReadEndpointRouteBuilder.java:61)
    at io.micronaut.management.endpoint.processors.AbstractEndpointRouteBuilder.lambda$process$0(AbstractEndpointRouteBuilder.java:106)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at io.micronaut.management.endpoint.processors.AbstractEndpointRouteBuilder.process(AbstractEndpointRouteBuilder.java:101)
    at io.micronaut.management.endpoint.processors.ReadEndpointRouteBuilder.process(ReadEndpointRouteBuilder.java:36)
    at io.micronaut.management.endpoint.processors.AbstractEndpointRouteBuilder.process(AbstractEndpointRouteBuilder.java:46)
    at io.micronaut.context.AnnotationProcessorListener.onCreated(AnnotationProcessorListener.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AnnotationProcessorListener.onCreated(AnnotationProcessorListener.java:45)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1523)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:2475)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfTypeInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2397)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:844)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.lambda$getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument$10(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1087)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanWithGenericsFromConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1695)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1082)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:961)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.$DefaultRouterDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1474)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

We have 3 environments: Development, Test and Production. It is working in development and test but not in production. We verified environment variables and jdk version. We are in cloud environment same image is being deployed in Dev, Test and Prod.

NA

Comment: Is the JDK/JRE the same in production?

Comment: JDK is same. We found the root cause. Dynatrace version was different. After disabling it, deployment was successful

Answer (score 1):

We found the root cause. Dynatrace version was different from test. After disabling it, deployment was successful